# $f$ is an odd function and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} [f(x)+x-1]= 0$. What is the asymptote of its restriction to $\mathbb{R}^-$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> About a function $f$, of domain $\mathbb{R}$, it is known that it is
>   odd and that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} [f(x)+x-1]= 0$. Let $g$ be
>   the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb{R}^-$. Which of the following lines
>   is the asymptote of the graph of function $g$?
>
> A) $y = x-1$
>
> B)$y = x+1$
>
> C)$y = -x-1$
>
> D)$y = -x+1$

I did:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} [f(x)+x-1]= 0 \Leftrightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} [f(x)-(-x+1)]= 0 \Leftrightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} [f(x)]= -x +1$$

So one of the asymptotes of $f$ is $-x+1$. Now, because the function is odd, this excludes options A) and B).

But what do I do next? My book says the solution is C), but I don't understand why. Shouldn't it be D)?

Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last step in your derivation reads $\lim f(x) = - x + 1$; this is incorrect, and of course what you mean is that $f(x) \sim (1-x)$ for $x \uparrow +\infty$. 
(The symbol $\sim$ reads "is asymptotic to".)

Now, recall that $f(x)$ is odd if $f(x) = - f(-x)$ for all $x$. Then $f(x) \sim (1-x)$ for $x \uparrow +\infty$ turns into $-f(-x) \sim (1-x)$ for $x \uparrow +\infty$. Replacing $t=-x$, this becomes $-f(t) \sim (1+t)$ for $t \downarrow -\infty$ or, equivalently, $f(t) \sim -(1+t)$ for $t \downarrow -\infty$. So C is correct.